# SEDE seems overloaded, is it true?

Tags: bug, data-explorer

Most of my queries I've developed worked pretty well while I've developed them, now most of them time out.

Has something uncommon happened, or are we simply overloaded?

Can I get information about the actual usage (or even usage history) of the SEDE? It would be important to know, so I would be more likely to write queries which work on more than Sunday nights.

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/649165/number-of-open-closed-and-deleted-questions-by-month) worked without any problem on Stack Overflow (14M question), but it won't work on Workplace (15k questions). Having a more than 1000x difference makes it realistic that there is something unusual happening.

Comment: Do you have an example query that times out for you?

Comment: Probably depends on what time of day you query. Also magic columns place a disproportionately heavy load on the query, it's something I know has been on TimStone's todo list for a long time. An example would help, we could help optimize it, too.

Comment: @rene Yes, I could make, but the topic of this question is not "how to optimize this query" (although I would be happy to ask this in a different question), rather "how to know that my question will work thuesday noon if I write it sunday night".

Comment: @peterh I understand but that makes it a broad question and the usefulness of my answer depends on so many factors you and I can't control. So if this is all you have then the answer will be: you can't.

Comment: @rene Ok. Specifically [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/649165/number-of-open-closed-and-deleted-questions-by-month) query leaded to ask this question. It runs without any problem even on the dbo.[StackOverflow], now it won't even run on the workplace SE. I tried many of my other queries, most of them don't work.

Comment: @JasonC Thanks. What are magic columns, are you thinking on the statical, constant, informative tables (*Types)?

Comment: @peterh No, the magic columns are those ones that turn into links, like `[Post Link]` and `[Comment Link]`.

Comment: @JasonC Wow, thanks! It surprises me, I've thought it is a purely clientonly thingy.

Comment: @peterh Also, btw: *"how to know that my question will work thuesday noon if I write it sunday night"* Query results are cached until sede is updated again (I think, not sure how long they last), so if you manage to execute it on a given site after a data update, you won't have to worry about it not working on Thursday on that same site as long as you don't modify it.

Comment: @JasonC Ok, thanks. But currently this query won't run on a small DB, while it once could run on the largest one. It looks an *unusually* big throughput difference to me.

Comment: @peterh I can't explain why your query *used* to work, it's a pretty hefty query, but for that specific case [this seems to get you what you want](http://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/674890), and much more quickly. The `FORMAT` is a bit slow, but ya know.

Comment: @JasonC Wow, it is brilliant! Thank you very much! Note, it worked, not even simply, but it was even *fast*... the linear scanning of the whole table is the worst thing and it couldn't be spared out, despite that it could work.

Comment: @peterh That is strange. We'll see if somebody answers this. Maybe something *has* changed.

Comment: IIRC they just made some sort of an update to SEDE, but I can't remember anything more.